# Does Winston's Tesla Cannon Penetrate Zarya's Barriers?

Tags: overwatch

I've been playing as [Winston](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Winston) more recently. He's very disruptive, and can act as a counter to Reinhardt because his Tesla Cannon ignores Reinhardt's barrier.

I believe it ignores an enemy Winston's barrier as well, all though I can't remember that happening to me with certainty.

Does it penetrate [Zarya](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zarya)'s barriers?

Specifically,

1. Will Zarya or one of her allies take damage from the Tesla Cannon even with an active barrier?
2. Will Zarya's energy level increase when one of her barriers is hit by a Tesla Cannon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not. Zarya's barriers will stop any damage, as well as a multitude of negative effects such as being slowed by Mei's ice and Zenyatta's Orb of Discord. This is also confirmed by the very wiki you linked:

> Particle Barrier behaves differently compared to normal barriers, acting more like additional Health than Reinhardt's Barrier Field. Attacks that normally pass through a barrier and deal damage, such as Winston's Tesla Cannon, will still have their damage and effects absorbed by Particle Barrier.

So yes, Zarya can charge up off a Winston's Tesla Cannon.

Comment: That's what it seemed like when I was playing this morning, but couldn't find any confirmation on the wiki. Those Zarya's were getting crazy. Evidence would be nice.

Comment: @DCShannon Is the Zarya link in your question good enough? "Particle Barrier behaves differently compared to normal barriers, acting more like additional Health than Reinhardt's Barrier Field. Attacks that normally pass through a barrier and deal damage, such as Winston's Tesla Cannon, will still have their damage and effects absorbed by Particle Barrier."

Comment: Ah, yep. Didn't see that note, clearly. Just quote that and I'll accept it.

Comment: Another note to make is that if Zarya is Discorded, popping her self shield will get rid of the discord.